# What is the Lambda handler Signature for AWS SDK V3 with TypeScirpt

Tags: aws-sdk-js

I'm updating an existing project from V2 to V3 of the AWS SDK for JavaScript and also moving our usage from JavaScript to TypeScript.

I'm struggling to define strongly typed handlers for the Lamdas.

The examples I've found are similar to this. I'm guessing that they're using V2 of the SDK.

```
export const lambdaHandler = async (event: APIGatewayEvent, context: Context): Promise<APIGatewayProxyResult> => {
    return {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify({
            message: 'hello world',
        }),
    };
};
```

I've had a look through the [V3 source](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3) for classes similar to `APIGatewayEvent`, `Context` and `APIGatewayProxyResult` but nothing jumps out at me as filling those roles.

Can someone please tell me how to strongly type these signatures?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AWS introduced the `@types/aws-lambda` package for use with there Javascript V3 SDK. Here is a typescript example, for your exact use case.

```
import { APIGatewayProxyHandler, APIGatewayEvent, APIGatewayProxyResult } from "aws-lambda";

export const handler: APIGatewayProxyHandler = async (event: APIGatewayEvent): Promise<APIGatewayProxyResult> => {
    return {statusCode: 200, body: event.body ?? ''};
}
```

Comment: But that is still pulling in `aws-lambda`, which itself relies on `aws-sdk` v2, right?

Answer (score 0):

I've been looking at [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html#example-standard-queue-message-event) and come up with the following:

```
import {HttpRequest as __HttpRequest,} from "@aws-sdk/protocol-http";
export const handler = async (
    eventIn: { Records: { body: string }[] },
    context: __HttpRequest
) => {}
```

Note that I only implemented body, but of course you could put messageId, receiptHandle etc at the same level.

Using [this](https://transform.tools/json-to-typescript) turns out the following

```
export type EventIn = {
  Records: Array<{
    messageId: string
    receiptHandle: string
    body: string
    attributes: {
      ApproximateReceiveCount: string
      SentTimestamp: string
      SenderId: string
      ApproximateFirstReceiveTimestamp: string
    }
    messageAttributes: {}
    md5OfBody: string
    eventSource: string
    eventSourceARN: string
    awsRegion: string
  }>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the new V2 type definitions like this:

```
import { APIGatewayProxyHandlerV2, APIGatewayProxyEventV2, APIGatewayProxyResultV2 } from 'aws-lambda';

export const handler: APIGatewayProxyHandlerV2 = async (event: APIGatewayProxyEventV2): Promise<APIGatewayProxyResultV2> => {
  const path =  event.requestContext.http.path;
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

[AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/typescript-handler.html#event-types) also recommends the following steps to generate type definitions for AWS Lambda that you can view/use in your project.

Note you'll need to have the AWS SAM CLI and the quicktype package installed.

```
sam local generate-event s3 put >> S3PutEvent.json
quicktype S3PutEvent.json -o S3PutEvent.ts
```

For S3 put events the documentation mentions the types `S3PutEvent` (see steps to generate above) and `S3Event` (mentioned by @rocketman). I had TypeScript issues with the generated one but it was helpful to dig into the code.